# Is there a way to list down the linked assembly names?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I want to list down the assembly names which are linked to my .exe. As I see in c#, we have an API which does the thing I want i.e. `"Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies"`
Description: Gets the AssemblyName objects for all the assemblies referenced by this assembly.

Similar to C#, can we get the list of libraries in c++.

It would be great if anyone could give me an advice.

Comment: There is no dedicated C++ API for this. You may want to check out utilities such as dependency walker or dumpbin. `dumpbin /DEPENDENTS prog.exe`

Comment: In C (and also partially C++) imported names (missing externals) look something like: `PleaseCallMe` and there is no meta-data attached to the symbol specifying what library need to be included.  The linker just fixes up (satisfies) the symbol with the fist matching name it finds from the list of libraries presented for linking.  [This is all oversimplified and does not even begin to address dynamic linking]

Comment: @VTT but there is Win32 API for it

Comment: if it is ok to use an external application - go for dependecywalker. if you wish to implement  it yourself you may be interested in corresponding Win32 API, like `EnumProcessModules`. Check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Do you really mean "linked assembly names", or do you mean "linked DLL's" ?

Comment: @RichardCritten: Incorrect. Imported names appear in the Import Address Table (IAT) of a PE (EXE or DLL). For each name, the IAT specifies the DLL name (including extension, but excluding path, in ASCII) from which the name is taken. 4th DWORD of each IAT entry is the Relative Virtual Address of the DLL name; the actual string is generally shared between functions imported from the same DLL.

Comment: @MSalters In my comment specifically excluded dynamically linked modules.  OP has (IMHO) 2 issues: statically linked and dynamically linked, I was only addressing the 1st.

Comment: @RichardCritten: I know. But you got the two reversed. Static linking uses the IAT and **does** attach metadata (DLL name). Dynamic linking **does not** attach metadata to function names, as it doesn't use the IAT.

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg, i tried that process. But it is not giving the DLL's linked to the application. I want the DLL's which we add as a dependency in the properties.

Comment: @Siva, I'm affraid I dont quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Given a number of C++ projects in your solution, which reference one another and finally linked into some executable. You want to see the list of all DLLs linked into the final executable, right?

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg, exactly. For instance, if I pass an executable name, I need to list down all the DLL's linked with it.

Comment: @Siva, dont you want to show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Open VS and create a new Win32 console application
Copy and paste below code. Run it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int PrintModules(DWORD processID)
{
    std::vector<HMODULE> modules;
    HANDLE process;
    DWORD bytesNeeded;

    std::cout << "Process ID:" << processID << std::endl;
    process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID);
    if(NULL == process)
        return 1;

    EnumProcessModulesEx(process, nullptr, 0, &bytesNeeded, LIST_MODULES_ALL);
    modules.resize(bytesNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE));
    if(EnumProcessModulesEx(process, modules.data(), modules.size() * sizeof(HMODULE), &bytesNeeded, LIST_MODULES_ALL))
    {
        for(auto handle : modules)
        {
            std::vector<char> moduleName(1024, 0);
            auto newSize = GetModuleFileNameEx(process, handle, moduleName.data(), moduleName.size());
            moduleName.resize(newSize);
            std::cout << "\t" << moduleName.data() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(process);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    PrintModules(GetCurrentProcessId());
    return 0;
}
```

You should get something like

> Process ID:9348
>           C:\Path\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.exe
>           C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
>           C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
>           C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
>           C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
>           C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140D.dll
>           C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ucrtbased.dll

Now add new Win32 DLL to the solution. Link your console application with it. Call any method from new library in your `main`. Something like this.

```
int main()
{
    auto res = fnMyLibrary();
    PrintModules(GetCurrentProcessId());
    return 0;
}
```

Rerun you program. You should get something like this

> Process ID:9348
>           C:\Path\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.exe
>           C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
>           C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
>           C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
>           C:\Path\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\Debug\MyLibrary.dll
>           C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
>           C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140D.dll
>           C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ucrtbased.dll

The whole solution is [here](https://github.com/kreuzerkrieg/StackOverflowStuff/tree/master/EnumProcessModulesSample/ConsoleApplication5)

Comment: ,Thanks for solution. As per your suggestion I tried this. But this is for a running process. What exactly I am trying to do is, There is an input given which is of exe path. Example: "c:xxxxmyexe", on providing an exe name i should list down the lib or dll files which we add it in the properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

Comment: Looks like you have to parse the PE directly and retrieve the data. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/YgRfypBslwM